# unable to digitally sign pdf using itext and java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

i am trying to put a basic digital signature on a pdf file. i am trying to use the code provided on the itext website.The code is as follows-

```
 public class DigiSign {
public static void main(String a[])
{
    try {

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\WSR\\keystore.ks"), "password".toCharArray());
        String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
        java.security.cert.Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\WSR\\a.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:\\WSR\\signed.pdf");
        PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
        sap.setCrypto(key, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
        sap.setReason("arpit");
        sap.setLocation("arpit");
        // comment next line to have an invisible signature
        sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20), 1, null);
        stp.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DigiSign.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

i created the key using

keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias myname -keypass password -keystore keystore.ks -dname "cn=Paulo Soares, c=PT"
and set abc123 as my password.
Now when i run this code i get this exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.getAppearance(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(Unknown Source)
    at DigiSign.main(DigiSign.java:42)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you have forgotten to add Bouncy Castle to your class path (or have the wrong version there). Furthermore you should look at this [white paper](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures/).

Comment: yeah i did forget to import bouncy castle to my project..added it..and the code is working now

Comment: Ouch, but you're using a signature type that is deprecated. Please read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures or your customer will be very disappointed when you deliver your code.

Comment: You say you've found that code on the iText website. Can you share the URL? Because I'm responsible for the iText website, and I don't find that code anywhere. If I found it, I'd remove it!

Comment: OK, maybe you were referring to http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html That page was so old I didn't even remember it. I've made a redirect to the most recent documentation.

Comment: yeah but that page appears first in the list of google search.ALso a lot of other similar questions on SE point to it

Answer (score 2):

(Just to formulate the cause as an answer which has been presented as a comment before:)

For security low level operations iText is based on the BouncyCastle libraries. This especially concerns creation and verification of integrated PDF signatures but also handling of encrypted documents. In these use cases, therefore, the appropriate BouncyCastle provider libs are required on the class path of the application.

The primary exception information

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
```

indicates that this requirement is not fullfilled, either BouncyCastle is not present at all or at least not present in the required version. This meanwhile has been confirmed by @user1946152 for his configuration.

P.S.: Obviously in the case at hand the OP still uses a pre-5.x version of iText. While there are certain conditions enforcing this (e.g. a management not being willing to decide when to buy a license *sigh*), you should definitively update to a current version of iText. There meanwhile have been many big changes, especially in the fields of electronic signatures, content parsing, and creation of PDF/A documents.